# Turn ESP8266 into an Arduino IDE-like "sketch uploader" (over hardware serial)

Tags: esp8266, arduino-mega, bootloader

I have an ESP8266 module which has downloaded a hex file for an Arduino Mega2560. This hex file (call it `mega2560.hex`) is sitting in the ESP's SPIFFS file system. What I want to do is basically emulate the behavior of the Arduino IDE when we press the upload button on a sketch (except in my case here, the sketch is already compiled and ready for transfer). What I need is some library or small code example that can steer me in the right direction. On the Mega's end, the processor will be restarted, and the bootloader will wait for the hex file, receive it from the ESP and flash it to application memory.

Here is the basic structure:

```
// Code for ESP8266
 
SoftwareSerial mega(D1, D2); // since hardware serial is occupied for serial monitor
// Mega will use its hardware serial (Tx1, Rx1)

void setup()
{
    Serial.begin(115200); // use up hardware serial
    mega.begin(115200); // connect to mega
    
    SPIFFS.begin();
    File hexfile = SPIFFS.open("mega2560.hex", "r");
    
    // IDE-like "upload"
    upload(mega, hexfile);
    Serial.println("Done uploading.");

    hexfile.close();
}

// emulate Arduino IDE-like upload behavior
void upload(SoftwareSerial& mega, File& hexfile)
{
    // reset Mega to start bootloader which will first wait to accept new hex file
    reset(mega);

    // send out the hex file for the bootloader to accept and store to Mega's flash
    send(mega, hexfile);

    // reset Mega to start bootloader again, this time so that previously uploaded hex file can be run
    reset(mega);
}
```

I am fairly new to working with bootloaders and would like to know if the above top-down code is correct in trying to achieve what I have in mind. Can I simply reset the Mega and transfer it as per usual via Serial within the bootloader's "waiting window" ? or are there more considerations that I am missing.

I am trying to avoid using ISP or SPI because that would erase the Mega's bootloader as well and I want to keep the bootloader preserved.

Comment: Yes, you are thinking in the right direction. You can simply reset the mega to get the mega bootloader started, but you can not just send the bytes through the serial port. Arduino bootloader uses STK500 commands for reliable handshaking. AVRdude uses the same protocol to talk to an Arduino. Here is a link that might give you some direction: https://www.electronicwings.com/arduino/basics-to-developing-bootloader-for-arduino

Comment: other option https://github.com/JAndrassy/lab/blob/master/AvrDudeTelnet/AvrDudeTelnet.ino